# What are the issues that may be encountered in created vagrant boxes if I don't use the default virtualbox ip ranges for machines

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vagrant, virtualbox-networking

I am working on Vagrant on my Ubuntu (20.04) and I learnt that the ip range allowed by default is ***192.168.56.0/21*** and that I can of course remove this restriction and use my own range.

I am new to vagrant and know if they are any inherent or severe results to use the `/etc/vbox/networks.conf` to set my own ip range. I am looking at using the ranges:

```
- 192.168.0.0/16
- 10.0.0.0/8
- 2001::/64
```

Apart from ip address conclusions for already created virtualbox machines why would this be a ***good*** or ***bad*** idea. I want to be able to set any ip address for my vagrant boxes for learning purposes.

Comment: Try as I might I do not see a question about Ubuntu here I see a question about Vagrant.

Comment: Yes, you are right let me move it to the right place for this. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not Ubuntu specific